# Getting online on my mac mini

Tags: macos, mac-mini, airport

I have a mac mini that I can't connect to the internet with.

I have a home network. I can go online fine with my ipad/cr-48, no problem.

But on OSX even though I can connect to the network via airport, it says Alert: no internet connection.

I tried to use the help, it tells me to restart the router and other stuff. I did, but still the same message.

Help me get online please, thanks!

Anybody?

Comment: What does System Preferences -> Network show for the connect you are using?

Comment: what do you mean the connect?

Answer (score 1):

Open System Preferences, go to Network, Select Airport on the left side, and verify that the first drop down is set to `Using DHCP`.  Secondly ensure you’re connecting to the proper access point.  What are the odds you’re accidentally on a neighbor’s network?  If both those conditions are true, you should see a bunch of numbers there (192.168.x.x, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.x.1, etc).

For future reference, simply telling us a problem exists isn’t going to get you answers.  Give us some more information: What kind of router do you have? Have you tried plugging the Mini directly in via a cable, just as a sanity check? Is the mini surrounded by a metal desk that may be clouding its ability to connect reliably, but your iPad which isn’t so enshrined is about to connect from almost the same spot flawlessly?  There are thousands of conditions that could be preventing this from working, but chances are its something painfully simple.  We just need more information to help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally those "No internet connection" messages have to do with a DNS issue. Your router is handing out IP addresses correct? Do you know what DNS information it is handing out? Have you verified that the Mac is receiving the correct DNS information?

Are there ay other devices on the network other than the Mac Mini and the iPad? Maybe something that you can use to ping the Mac Mini?

Comment: I have 2 other windows computers yes. Please give me instructions on how to check things on the mac.

Answer (score 0):

Check the router settings.  Your Mac may be in a blacklist of MAC addresses. (MAC = "Media Access Control and in this context has nothing to do with Macintosh.)

Open a terminal and type:

```
ifconfig
```

I'm not a Mac expert, you may have to use an administative account or sudo to make that work.

Edit your question to show the result.

Carl